# Проверка e-mail на существование

Tags: php, email

Как можно определить e-mail на существование на php? 
Можно конечно через этот [сервис](http://2ip.ru/mail-checker/) curl запросы отправлять. Но хотелось бы узнать, как они это сделали.

Comment: Че-то слышал, что проверка на регулярках занимает около килобайта текста (чисто регулярки).

[Примеры, найденные поиском](http://phpclub.ru/talk/threads/%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-email.24915/)

Как вариант еще - посмотреть как реализовано в ZF

Comment: самый надежный способ - бегло проверить регуляркой, а потом отправить письмо с просьбой ответить. Сервис, который ТС привел недоговаривает, что почтовые сервера абсолютно не объязаны отвечать, существует ли данный адрес. А вот если письмо попытаться отправить, то они ответят (хотя не факт что сразу). Все от спаммеров защищаются как могут.

Да, тот сервис отсекает заведомо верные эмейлы, так что...

Comment: @ВОРОН, проверка регулярками это скорее всего проверка на валидность а не на существование.

Comment: А зачем вообще проверять на существование?

Для активации? Так если пользователь указал не верный email, то он ее (активацию) не пройдет. Кроме того можно указать и не свое мыло - адрес валидный, но не мой.

Если нужен именно мой адрес - тогда достаточно простой валидации. А дальше активировать мое мыло, либо забыть про него, если активация не была произведена.

Или вопрос ради праздного любопытства?

Comment: кстати да. И правда, зачем?

Comment: У ТС чисто спортивный интерес. Вполне даже адекватный.

Comment: если чисто спортивный, то норм. просто если это чтото вроде "хочу на форум прикрутить", то это узиобретание велосипеда скорее всего будет. Ну и судя по второму предложению, то так и есть (про форум/сайт и т.п.) есть специяльные службы с АПИ, которые это проверяют. На форуме у меня стоит и левых емылов не пропускает.

Comment: Чудной заказчик, не понимаю зачем ему это, объяснить не может. Но пользоваться аккаунтом с неверным имейлом пользователь не сможет, т.к. пароль приходит на указанный имейл.

Comment: Этот ваш сервис сказал, что моего ящика нет... любопытно..

Comment: сервис гавно, и впринципе другие сервисы не намного лучше, полностью правду ни один сервис не говорит

Comment: А про мой уже не существующий (*реально шлюз, слушающий интернет письмо примет, а дальше будет отлуп*), сказал что такой e-mail есть.

--

Резюме. Сервис просто обман.

--

@mctrane, боюсь что в *общем случае* это неразрешимая задача (даже не онлайн).

Если считать, что все MTA в цепочке поддерживают ESMTP, то можно заказать подтверждение доставки в дополнительных параметрах RCPT TO, и MTA, вызвавший финальный mailer, сформирует сообщение (почту) о доставке либо кто-то в процессе доставки письма выкинет его и пошлет сообщение о недоставке.

Но это письмо (понятно, не мгновенно).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

в ТЕОРИИ сделать можно, но не везде.

по поводу гугла:

```
telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25

helo example.com
mail from: <me@example.com>
rcpt to: <somenonexistinguser@gmail.com>
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=6596
```

а если пользователь существует, то будет ответ:

```
250 2.1.5 OK
```

вот более [полный расписанный ответ](https://superuser.com/questions/207926/if-to-and-from-headers-are-the-spammers-email-address-how-did-i-get-this-e/208156#208156)

Все это вполне может работать и для других серверов.

Answer (score 7):

Не уверен, что это программируется на ПХП.

Видимо наиболее реально попробовать соединиться с сервером (узнав по MX в DNS его адрес) по SMTP и "начать отправку почты", послать в итоге

```
RCPT TO: проверяемый@адрес
```

и если ответ положительный, то *можно предполагать*, что такой e-mail существует.

Comment: еще некоторые сервера поддерживают `VRFY user`

Comment: Есть такие слова в протоколе. Но чаще эта фича заблокирована, а адрес существует.

Comment: да, согласен, поэтому и написал, что НЕКОТОРЫЕ.

Comment: К сожелению, похоже на то, что некоторые почтовые серваки будут ложно проверять. Например на многих сервисах какой бы я н еввёл имейл на mail.ru вседа пишет, что имейл существует.

Answer (score 0):

1. см. комментарий.
2. я это [нашел!](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)
3. На [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/55820/) расписано что, где и как.
4. В том же топике хабра есть [коммент](http://habrahabr.ru/post/55820/#comment_1495462).
5. Можно и самому придумать какой-нибудь способ)

Comment: М-да... Не вник в вопрос) Ну ладно, для общего развития тоже будет полезно)

Comment: Не люблю я минусы ставить, вот не люблю)

Comment: По поводу регулярок, проверяющих соответствие RFC-822 могу сказать, что соответствие адреса RFC вовсе не означает, что его поймут (может дойти не соответствующий RFC адрес, а может не дойти, соответствующий).

Дело  в том, что *на практике* все еще полно МТА, которые разбирают адреса "поверхностно" (плохо они запрограммированы). 

Я уже не говорю о том, что формально правильный домен может в реальности и не существовать.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isEmail ($email) {
   return preg_match("/^([a-z0-9_-]+\.)*[a-z0-9_-]+@[a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i",$email);
}
```

Comment: Опять же это проверка валидности email а не его существования.

Comment: @KryDos, чукча не читатель, чукча писатель)

Comment: А код то показывает плохой пример. Мало того, что классическое индусское `return true; else return false`, так ещё выражение, которое отсечет много правильных эмейлов. Посмотрели бы хотя бы на верные в [википедии](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address) и [rfc](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc822)

`"very.(),:;<>[]\".VERY.\"very@\\ \"very\".unusual"@strange.example.com` - хоть и верный, но этот фильтр не пройдет.

Comment: А также `root` и `postmaster@localhost` тоже будут отброшены.

IMHO одной регуляркой эта задача не решается, сомневающиеся могут почитать какой-нибудь sendmail.cf

Comment: Тема определения валидности формата email давно обмусолена в интернетах. Погуглите — адрес может содержать адовы символы, и при этом быть валидным, а более-ли-менее корректный регэксп, проверяющий его имеет длину около килобайта. Приведённый вами пример далёк от «совершенства».

Comment: в любом случае ответ не по теме ТС :)

Answer (score 0):

этого сделать нельзя в принципе

провалидировать правильность написания адреса согласно стандарту - это пожалуйста

Comment: "где ващи доказатьельства?" (ц) Красная жара :)

Comment: преположим мы хотим узнать есть ли адрес pupkin@gmail.com,
и что по вашему - google выдаст вам информацию о сущестововании пользователя? - групости, т.к. это конфиденциальная информация

или вот pupkin@mailinator.com - тут mailinator - наоборот будет вам говорить что у него есть пупкин, и все-все-все остальные, кого бы не проверяли... сервис такой, что ж поделаешь...

это просто логические рассуждения - уверен - общего подхода для определения сущестования пользвателя на почтовом сервере не существует (если вы не админ этого сервера естесственно)

Comment: я к тому, что "нельзя сделать в принципе", в ТЕОРИИ сделать можно, но не везде.

по поводу гугла:

    telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
    
    helo example.com
    mail from: <me@example.com>
    rcpt to: <somenonexistinguser@gmail.com>
    550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
    550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
    550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
    550 5.1.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=6596

а если пользователь существует, то будет ответ:

    250 2.1.5 OK

Comment: вот более [полный расписанный ответ](http://superuser.com/questions/207926/if-to-and-from-headers-are-the-spammers-email-address-how-did-i-get-this-e/208156#208156)

Comment: а я как раз и говорю про то что "в ТЕОРИИ сделать можно", но нет "общего подхода для определения существования"

220 mail.mailinator.com ESMTP Postfix
helo example.com
250 mail.mailinator.com
mail from: <somenoexistingatalluser@mailinator.com>
250 Ok
rcpt to: <somenonexistingusernblabla@mailinator.com>
250 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
hi

.
250 Ok

Comment: ну как нет общего подхода, есть rfc какбэ) как раз общий подход есть, результаты могут разниться от сервера к серверу, изза ограничений, введенных администрацией сервера.

Comment: да, rfc определяет 550 код как "no such user"

и хорошо, согласен - общий подход есть, но работать он будет далеко не везде, а следовательно не может быть применен со 100% гарантией 

я вот для сомнительных сайтов всегда использую сервисы типа mailinator.com

и потом - потом лучшим способом будет все таки подтверждение пользователем своего существования путем проведения каких-то манипуляций с письмом от сервера приславшего запрос

определить smtp сервер для почтового адреса, тоже не всегда просто

Comment: по поводу http : // 2ip.ru / mail-checker /

    Обратите пожалуйста внимание, не каждый почтовый сервис отвечает на наши запросы, поэтому мы не можем гарантировать абсолютной точности выдаваемых результатов.