# Как реализовать проверку email на существование? ajax json mysqli php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, mysqli

Не знаю как сделать проверку на существование email при обновлении таблицы БД, помогите пожалуйста.
Локальный сервер у меня если что

Вот файл update.php

```
<?php require_once("connection.php");

    global $con;

    session_start();

    $response = array();

    if (isset($_POST['userData'])) {
        $id = (int)$_POST['id'];
        $full_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['full_name']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
        $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phone']);

        if (checkEmail($email) && checkSID()) {

            $queryString = "UPDATE `usertbl` 
        SET full_name='$full_name', 
            email='$email', 
            phone='$phone'
        WHERE id='$id'";

            $query = mysqli_query($con, $queryString);

            $array = array(
                "status" => 200,
                "content" => "Данные успешно обновлены!"
            );

            if (mysqli_affected_rows($con)) {

                echo json_encode($array);

            } else {

                $array["status"] = 406;
                $array["content"] = "Вы ничего не изменили! о_О";

                echo json_encode($array);

            }
        }


        function checkEmail($email)
        {
            global $con;
            require_once("connection.php");
            /**
             * email exists in database
             * return regExp (boolean)
             */
            $pattern = "/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/";
            $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email FROM usertbl WHERE email='$email'");


            if (preg_match($pattern, $email) && ($arr [0]['email'] == $email)
            ) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

        function checkSID () {
            /**
             * return session (boolean)
            */

           return ($_SESSION["session_username"] !== "");
       }

    ?>
```

И ajax.js

```
$("#registerform").on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData(document.forms.editForm);
    formData.append("userData", true);

            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/user/update.php',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: formData,
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);

                    if (response.status === 200)
                        $(".success").html(response.content);
                    else
                        $(".success").html(response.content);

                }
            });
});
```

Comment: Флудить не хочу, комментарий не является ответом и близко не стоял там, но я где-то раньше видел код, который опрашивал домен на существование ящика (могу ошибаться), таким образом проверяя валидность почтового ящика. Просто это давно было, лет 6 назад

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проверка e-mail на существование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/187642/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-e-mail-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Comment: А зачем проверять? Если вы отсылаете, к примеру, подтверждение обновления почтового ящика на НОВЫЙ ящик (ссылка с подтверждением в теле письма), то ответственность будет лежать на пользователе. Плюс в том что вы сразу же не обновляете адрес, а только при получении уникального кода подтверждения из ссылки, которая доступна только в почтовом ящике владельца.

Comment: Еще раз? уточни ты хочешь проверить что почта есть у юзера или есть ли такая почта в базе? поле ***email*** в базе должно быть уникальным. Если нету такого мыла пропускаешь функцию, нет возвращаешь к заполнению мыла.

Comment: @DaemonHK нее ... с дублем не угадал... вот его дубль https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/740535/191482 ..... ну и клон заодно :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский приведенный Вами вопрос уже удален)) Я может не угадал, просто нашел похожий вопрос.

Comment: @DaemonHK да, он удален  из-за моего комментария тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/741096/internal-server-error-500-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%91%D0%94-ajax-json-php-js#comment1133108_741096  :D Подчищает вопросы у своего  второго аккаунта :)